# Maintaining viewstate of a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, viewstate, asprepeater

I have a problem whereby the viewstate of a repeater i.e. the controls within the repeater are not maintaing their viewstate.

I have the following:

Repeater 1:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton Text="Add" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument=<%# Eval("ID") %> runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When the link button is clicked the value of the CommandArgument is stored in a hidden field on the page.

Upon postback I can't get the value of the hidden field until the prerender event handler has loaded. So in my prerender event I grab the value of the hidden field and store it in a List property, like so:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SelectedImageIDsInput.Text)) {
        this.ImageList.Add(this.SelectedImageIDsInput.Text);
    }
```

And the List property looks like so:

```
public List<string> ImageList {
    get {
        if (this.ViewState["ImageList"] == null) {
            this.ViewState["ImageList"] = new List<string>();
        }
        return (List<string>)(this.ViewState["ImageList"]);
    }
    set { this.ViewState["ImageString"] = value; }
}
```

Once I have stored the value into my List property I bind my second repeater (again within the prerender event):

```
this.rptSelectedImages.DataSource = this.LightBoxControl.ImageList;
this.rptSelectedImages.DataBind();
```

The second repeater has a dropdownlist and a textbox within it. The problem is that the viewstate of these child controls is not maintained. I presume it is because with each postback I am rebinding the repeater, therefore it is rebuilt. What I don't know is how I can possibly get round this? The ImageList property is only updated upon a postback, so I obviously have to rebind the repeater with each postback - how else can it be done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Al

Comment: Possible workaround is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106148/rebinding-repeater-in-an-event-loses-its-viewstate-on-its-controls

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are rebinding the repeater, you need to do it on `Init` before the `ViewState` is loaded.

You should also check the `IsPostback` flag and only Bind the repeater when the page is not posted back.

To clarify if your second repeater is bound on `PreRender` then `ViewState` cannot be used to persist the controls, because they simply don't exist when `ViewState` is loaded - after `Init`, and before `PreLoad`.

You either need to continue binding on every postback, or store or list in `Session` so that you have access to the list to bind once on `Init`, (or on change).

Comment: Hi CodeKing. Two problems there though - I can't get the value of the hidden field as early as the Init event - plus the ImageList property can only be updated on postback.....

Comment: In that case you would need to rebind the second repeater on every call using the value in the hidden field.

Comment: Hi CodeKing - thats exactly what I'm doing though isnt it? Am i misunderstanding your response. I currently wait until the onprerender to get the value of the hidden field and then re-bind the repeater - the problem with this is the viewstate of the controls in the repeater dont persist over postbacks....

Comment: In order for controls to persist with ViewState they must exist prior to PreLoad. This is because ViewState is loaded after Init and before PreLoad. If you are binding your repeater on PreRender you cannot use ViewState.

Comment: Hi CodeKing - your feedback hasn't got the page working entirely, but it has fixed the viewstate issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of copying the `CommandArgument` property to a hidden field. What you should do is to use the `ItemCommand` event on the `Repeater` and use event bubbling. You can handle the `Click` event on you `LinkButton` like this:

```
repeater.ItemCommand += (sender, eventArgs) => {  
   var commandArgument = eventArgs.CommandArguments;
   ImageList.Add(commandArgument);
   rptSelectedImages.DataSource = ImageList;
   rptSelectedImages.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mikael - I know it seems crazy to copy it to a hidden field. The problem is I also have a jQuery image upload on the same page - once the file has uploaded the handler returns the new ImageId - of course JS can't call ImageList.Add so it has to be stored in a hidden field. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Repeater
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private List<test> list = null;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack == false)
            {
                list = new List<test> { new test { Title = "aaaa" }, new test { Title = "bbb" } };
                Repeater1.DataSource = list;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            if (savedState != null)
            {
                // Load State from the array of objects that was saved at ;
                // SavedViewState.
                object[] myState = (object[])savedState;
                if (myState[0] != null)
                {
                    list = Deserialize((string)myState[0]);
                    Repeater1.DataSource = list;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                }
                if (myState[1] != null)
                    base.LoadViewState(myState[1]);
            }
        }

        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object baseState = base.SaveViewState();
            object[] allStates = new object[2];
            allStates[1] = baseState;
            allStates[0] = Serialize();
            return allStates;
        }

        string Serialize()
        {
            var writer = new StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<test>));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);

            var xml = writer.ToString();
            return xml;
        }
        List<test> Deserialize(string xml)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<test>));

            var deserializedBook = (List<test>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
            return deserializedBook;
        }
    }

    public class test
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```