# Storing and restoring properties in ASP.NET derived control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

I have created an ASP.NET class derived from the standard `WebControls.TextBox`, with the intention of adding extra properties that will persist between post-backs. However, I cannot figure how to get the values in these properties to persist.

I have tried setting the value of the properties into the controls `ViewState` as part of the `PreRender` handler, but the value is then not accessible in the `Init` handler on the post-back, because the `ViewState` has not yet been setup.

I *could* look for the `ViewState` value in the `Load` handler of the control, but if the page/usercontrol that is using the control asks for the properties value during its `Load` handler, the control hasn't yet reached it's `Load` handler, and it therefore not there.

My current class looks something like this...

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private _myParam As String = ""
    Public Property MyParam As String
        Get
            Return _myParam
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _myParam = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub MyTextBox_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            _myParam = ViewState("myParam")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyTextBox_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        ViewState("myParam") = _myParam
    End Sub
End Class
```

I must be missing something really simple, such as whether there is an attribute I can set against the property.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @AVD pointing out that I really had very little clue about the ViewState and the Init / Load stages, I finally figured it all out.

If you have the time (and if you're doing any major ASP.NET work, you *need* to make the time) please read the [Understand ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) document that @AVD pointed me to. It will explain a lot.

However, what it didn't explain is if you place your control within a `<asp:Repeater>`, you may as well throw all the rules out of the window... and that is exactly the problem I was experiencing.

In the end, the way I managed to get it to work was to use a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control within the repeater, create an instance of my control within the `ItemDataBound` handler of the repeater, and then add the control to the `<asp:PlaceHolder>`... all done within the `Init` section (which fortunately I'm able to do).

As [Andrew found out in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575414/problem-with-viewstate-of-dynamic-controls-inside-a-repeater) you can end up in a chicken/egg situation, where you need to create the controls in the `Init`, but you won't know what controls you need until the `Load`.

(I have still made AVD's answer the correct one, because in the context of my original question, it is absolutely correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store/retrieve value to/from ViewState within the properties accessors.

```
Public Property MyParam As String
    Get
       If IsNothing(ViewState("myParam")) Then
           return string.Empty
       End IF
       Return ViewState("myParam").ToString()
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("myParam") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get this to work - I still have the issue that the ViewState is not initialised at the point that the parent page/usercontrol requests the information (as part of it's `Load` handler)

Comment: @freefaller Do not use _myParam and I don't understand why are you retrieving ViewState in **init** and assigning in **prerender** handler.

Comment: Because I was trying to get it to work. Unfortunately I am still hitting the same problem, no matter how I use your code. If the control is hosted on a page, and that page retrieves ctrl.MyParam as part of the pages `Load` handler, the value is still blank... because I believe the `ViewState` for the derived controls still hasn't been initialised (at least it always shows as `Nothing` as far as I can see)

Comment: @freefaller I'd suggest to read this [MSDN doc - Init and load view stage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: I thought I had a handle on how this stuff worked... I'm currently reassessing that view! Wow, my head hurts. I'm now in a Catch22 situation where I need to create dynamic controls in the Init section, but using values that are only available in the page's Load section. Thanks for your help, and apologies for thinking I knew more than I obvious do

Comment: I've finally got it all sorted, and the part that was missing from all the above (and a really apologise for missing this out, but I didn't think it was relevant) is that the control in question is held in a `<asp:Repeater>`.  After lots of research, it turns out that ASP.NET is really not very good at handling dynamicaly set variables on dynamic controls (whether derived or not) when contained within a repeater (unless those controls are added manually on bind).  Apologies again